# Implementing Store Pattern in Vue.js

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I am trying to implement the store pattern in Vue.js and I am stuck. I have two child components that get shared state passed to them via props. Each child component does something different with the props passed in. `comp-a` has an input and two buttons where the user can add words to a list or empty out the list altogether, while `comp-b` is responsible for mapping over and displaying the array of words. I am able to map over the array of words like so:

```
Vue.component('comp-b', {
   props: ['astore'],
   template: '#comp-b',
   data: function(){
     return {
       words: store.state.words
     }
   },
   computed: {
     theWords: function(){
       return this.words.map(function(word){
         return word
      })
   }
  }
})
```

I am having some difficulty figuring out how to empty the word list such that by clicking the `Empty words` button it updates what is being displayed in `comp-b` (which should be nothing since words have now been cleared from the word list)

Here is a demo: http://codepen.io/p-adams/pen/oLpzPA

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To clear out the array you can use

`clear: function(){
    return this.state.words.splice(0);
 }`

Based on this https://vuejs.org/guide/list.html#Mutation-Methods VueJS triggers view update when using splice.

Comment: That worked. Thanks! Just out of curiosity, why doesn't it work if I just set this.state.words to an empty array when clear() is called?

Comment: I am new to Vue so I am not fully aware of how change detection works in vue. I was surprised as well why that doesn't work. Just guessing but maybe because [] creates a new array and doesn't have reference to the original array vue doesn't trigger the change detection.